# jQuery: Problems with getting OKZoom started

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to use [OKZoom](http://okfoc.us/okzoom/), but it does not work. I created this simple example:

```js
$('img').okzoom({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  round: true,
  background: "#fff",
  backgroundRepeat: "repeat",
  shadow: "0 0 5px #000",
  border: "1px solid black"
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/okfocus/okzoom/master/src/okzoom.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/eulKI.jpg">
</div>
```

What is missing here?

Would be very thankful for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

it works on codepen, i just add document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#myimg").okzoom({
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    border: "1px solid black",
    shadow: "0 0 5px #000"
  });

})
```

https://codepen.io/AlibiGhazi/pen/NWNNmPG